# iOS 2 UITableViews and change hidden property or 1 and change source

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to use segmented control to switch between "two" tables but I am not sure what would be best aproach. Should I really create 2 tables and change hidden property when segmented control value is changed or should I changed data source and global property which then helps me detect which data I want show?

If there would be same custom cell for each table than I guess best aproach would be with one table. But I created 2 custom cells (with xib and custom class, because content is a little different) for each table so I am not sure.  Something like this in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
if(_firstContent)
    CellIdentifier = @"trackIdentifier";
else
    CellIdentifier = @"otherIdentifier";

UITableView *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (!cell)
{
    if(_firstContent)
    {
         [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"PanelTrackCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier;
         cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    else
    {
         [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"PanelOtherCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
         cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
}
```

Is this good aproach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach will be using one table and changing data inside this table. Your cellForRow method is totally legal, this approach is using always when data can be totally different inside cells, but if it real, you should use Auto-Layout and using one cell.

Using two tables isn't good idea because then you will need to controller hidden property of them and also using exactly same cellForRow method. So yes, your approach is good.